# Can’t use optical flow function

Tags: c#, emgucv, opticalflow

I am using in Visual Studio 2019, and emgucv 3.3.0.2824.
In this version of emgucv I can’t find optical flow alg. and I know that in the emgucv 2.4.9.1847 version there is the opticalflow.hs func. But in my version, I don’t succeed to use opticalflow alg. In my code I split video into frames and converted each frame to gray scale. Now I want to use these frames for the optical flow alg. So that my output will be a video in gray scale and the object that I’m moving will be marked in red or green square.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

This is the code (in private async void ReadAllFrames() func):

```
private async void ReadAllFrames()
{
    Mat m = new Mat();
    //read all the frames
    while (isReadingFrames == true && FrameNo < TotalFrame)
    {
        FrameNo += Convert.ToInt16(numericUpDown1.Value);
        capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.PosFrames, FrameNo);
        capture.Read(m);//read the frame that we choose in the upper line
        pictureBox2.Image = m.Bitmap;
        Bitmap img = null;
        if (FrameNo < TotalFrame)
        {
            img = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image);
        }
        if (FrameNo < TotalFrame)
        {
            imgInput = new Image<Bgr, byte>(m.Bitmap);
            Image<Gray, byte> imgOutput =
                new Image<Gray, byte>(m.Bitmap.Width, m.Bitmap.Height, new Gray(0));
            imgOutput = imgInput.Convert<Gray, byte>();
            pictureBox3.Image = imgOutput.Bitmap;
            await Task.Delay(1000 / Convert.ToInt16(Fps));
            label1.Text = FrameNo.ToString() + "/" + TotalFrame.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
  protected  TrackingPoint[] TrackFrame(Mat lastImage,Mat currentImage, PointF[] pointToLookFor,int index)
        {
            PointF[] nextPts;
            byte[] status;
            float[] errors;                
            CvInvoke.CalcOpticalFlowPyrLK(lastImage, currentImage, pointToLookFor, new Size(30, 30), 1, new MCvTermCriteria(20, 0.03), out nextPts, out status, out errors);
            var returnList = new List<TrackingPoint>();
            for(int i=0;i<status.Length;i++)
            {
                returnList.Add(new TrackingPoint()
                {
                    index=index,
                    status = status[i] == 1 ? true : false,
                    toPoint = nextPts[i],
                    fromPoint = pointToLookFor[i]

                }
                    );
            }            

            return returnList.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```